# Wireguard wg0.conf file: what fields may it (not?) contain?

Tags: wireguard

The Ubuntu [man page for wg](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/wg.8.html) has a Configuration File Format portion. That portion says of the .conf file's [Interface] and [Peer] sections that they "may contain the following fields." Am I right in surmising that "may" is meant permissively, and not in the sense of "may only contain"? E.g., I've seen several examples which include an `Address` field in the [Interface] section -- a virtual network IP address -- but it's not among those included in the man page; and [the setup tutorial at Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-wireguard-on-ubuntu-22-04) includes in its [Interface] examples fields such as `PostUp`, `SaveConfig`, and `DNS`.

More generally, can the .config contain any setting that can be issued to the shell with the wg command?

Answer (score 1):

Configuration files may contain any field, tools will just ignore those that aren't recognized.

There are **two** very similar configuration formats used by different programs:

- The `wg` tool strictly deals with *only* the WireGuard-related parameters – peers, keys, but not inner IP configuration nor DNS nor firewalls.
- The [`wg-quick`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/wg-quick.8.html) script tries to be a high-level wrapper that'll bring up the entire "VPN connection" from start to end – it'll create the tunnel interface, apply tunnel settings via `wg`, assign IP addresses and insert routes via `ip`, define DNS server addresses via `resolvconf` or systemd-resolved, and even run arbitrary shell commands (e.g. insert iptables rules).

Answer (score 0):

My question is largely answered by [the man page for wg-quick](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/wg-quick.8.html). All of the [Interface] fields I mentioned in the question are discussed there.

And here I thought the "M" in RTFM was for "Manual" rather than "man."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).